# how to step into C++ code while debugging python using DDD(or gdb)

Tags: python, c++, boost, gdb, ddd-debugger

For test example, I have this test C++ class which I exported to Python using boost.(from boost website)

```
#include <boost/python.hpp>
using namespace boost::python;

struct WorldC
{
    void set(std::string msg) { this->msg = msg; }
    std::string greet() { return msg; }
    std::string msg;
};

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(hello)
{
    class_<WorldC>("WorldP")
        .def("greet", &WorldC::greet)
        .def("set", &WorldC::set)
    ;
}
```

I compiled this code by `g++ -g -shared -o hello.so -fPIC hello.cpp -lboost_python -lpython2.7 -I/usr/local/include/python2.7` and tested it ok.  The test script `pp1.py` is like this :

```
import hello
a = hello.WorldP()
a.set('ahahahah')    # <-- line 3
print a.greet()
print('print1')
b = hello.WorldP()
b.set('bhbhbhbh')
print b.greet()
print('print2')
print('program done')
```

This code runs ok either in interacitive mode and as a script.

```
ckim@stph45:~/python/hello] python pp1.py
ahahahah
print1
bhbhbhbh
print2
program done
```

I'm using DDD for visual debugging. When I give the command `ddd -pydb pp1.py`, I can do Python code debugging. When I'm inside the debugger, I can give `next` command and see the result. But when the debugger is for example in line 3, when I give `step` command, it just passes the line not entering into the c++ code. How can I make this work?
(I tried with just gdb, but it's the same- not entering into c++ code.)

Comment: you could (temporarily) try to insert `__asm__("int $3")` in the code of your C++ module, see if gdb/DDD catches it.

Comment: it catches the interrupt. then what can I do more? though I want to set breakpoints dynamitcally..

Comment: do you see the source? Have you tried `info shared` to see which dll is loaded and if there is a `(*)` to indicate that symbols are loaded?

Comment: I see the python source, but when interrupt is caught, I see the message `PYDB terminated abnormally(Trace/breakpoint trap)`. For `info shared`, I get `Undefined info command shared`. Thanks for trying to help..:)

Comment: What add-on are you using with gdb to single-step python code?

Comment: I don't know. I installed pydb1.26 which is an extended version of Python debugger pdb.py. pdb.py works with GUI frontend ddd. (I checked the README file of pydb1.26 now that you asked)`.. Hmm maybe I was not using gdb. (the README says it's trying to follow gdb command).

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre see my answer,  now I can debug C++ while runnig python program! :)